# Paypal Error 10712 your zip code is invalid in billing details

Tags: paypal

I am try to do directy payment with but I am getting error 10712. Here is array that I am posting to paypal.

```
[card_fname] => Angela
[card_lname] => Taylor
[emailAddress] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
[card_name] => MasterCard
[card_number] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[exp_month] => 1
[exp_year] => 2014
[card_secu_code] => xxx
[country] => AU
[street] => xxxxxxxxxxx St,
[city] => Sydney 
[state] => NSW
[zip] => 2000
[currency]=>AUD
```

Anybody can help why i am getting this errors. All the parameters are correct i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Reading paypal developer's documentation it says it requires a 5 digits zip code since your country uses 4 digits you might wanna try appending a 0 in front of the zip code. Try it and see if it works.